# Does ResolveUrl work for ../../ as well?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I wanted to know, would ResolveUrl only work if you do ../ or / or will it also work for ../../  ?

so for examples im using ResolveUrl when using external javascript files

```
<script src="../../js/Plugins/jquery.contextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I replaced all my scrips tags that only have ../ with ResolveUrl and it seems to work.Will it also work for the code above?

Comment: Can you not just try it and see? I would have thought it would take less time than searching for the answer and then asking here would have done... The docs may be helpful too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx

Comment: The best thing that can be done is test it for yourself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work for that too, but I suggest using some context paths rather than having a large number of `../`.

Comment: I've been using ResolveUrl for all of them but I just wasn't too sure about the ../../